# Receiving .mp4 over TCP socket (C++/Java)

Tags: java, android, c++, file, sockets

I'm working on a project which requires transmitting a MP4 video from a Java (Android) server to a C++ (Visual studio) client.

Everything works fine if I use a Java Client, but with the C++ client I receive a file 1 byte larger that the file sent. As a result, the file won't obviously open. I don't know if the problem is just with that extra bit or there is something else wrong.

Here's the relevant code of my C++ Client:

```
FILE *myFile=std::fopen("scan.mp4","wb");
char *recVideoBuffer=new char[videoSize];//videoSize previously received        

int written;
totalBytesRcvd = 0;
while (totalBytesRcvd < videoSize)
{

    if ((bytesRcvd = recv(sock, recVideoBuffer, videoSize, 0)) <= 0)
        DieWithError("recv() failed or connection closed prematurely");
    totalBytesRcvd += bytesRcvd;   /* Keep tally of total bytes */
    if ((written = fwrite(recVideoBuffer, 1, bytesRcvd, myFile)) != bytesRcvd)
        DieWithError("fwrite() failed");

    printf("Filesize: %d\nReceived: %d\Written %d\nTotal Received: %d\n\n", videoSize, bytesRcvd, written, totalBytesRcvd); 

}
fclose(myFile);  
closesocket(sock);
```

Java Server:

```
            File source = new File (VIDEO_FILE);    
            byte byteArray[] = new byte [(int)source.length()];
            BufferedInputStream bStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));
            bStream.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
            OutputStream outStream = s.getOutputStream();
            outStream.write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            bStream.close();
            s.close();
            server.close();
```

Any ideas on what the problem(s) might be and how to fix them?
I've looked around and found some related questions but those were either unanswered or not relevant...

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

I tried sending a 'abcde' .asc file, and the client receives just 'abcd'. In this case both the files are 5 byte large though.

===

I looked into the byte values of the MP4 files.
The received one has 2 extra bytes, `0a`, at the beginning, and is missing the last 2B. Manually changing these values makes the video play correctly.

Where does `0a` come from? Obviously because of those 2B the last 2 are not written...

**SOLVED**

Quite a silly issue really... I would send the video size using `println()`, which `recv()` couldn't read entirely, apparently *leaving* those `0a` bytes over the socket, ready to be received by the next `recv()` along with the file bytes. 
That explains why everything worked with the Java client, as I would read the videoSize using `readLine()` .
How annoying having wasted a day on this, Lol.

Comment: How can a file be 1 bit larger?

Comment: Yeah sorry EDIT: I mean 1 byte. Like: source filesize: 10000 bytes, total bytes received: 10001 bytes

Comment: What is the `std:fill()` for?

Comment: @EJP Cleaning the array, but it doesn't make any difference really.

Comment: Correct. It's pointless. So remove it.

Comment: Maybe that's because of null terminator?

Comment: @EJP Done, still the main issue remains unsolved...

Comment: @ForceBru I thought about it, but what do you suggest? I tried not to write to file the last byte I receive, so the file size matches the source one, but the mp4 is still corrupted.

Comment: Well, you can compare the original and received files to see where's the difference.

Comment: Have you tried sending a long ascii 'a' text file? Easy to see if it corrupts files